# You're Invited!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

One early morning while you check your mailbox, you see a letter. You open it and read:

> *~ For people who like Gray Test, Red Lid, Wordy Pal, people who build
>   Carport Gym or even who Swap Rods ~*
>
> Hi this is Paul, also known as "Mr. Party Cog". I'm inviting you to my
>   place so you can join the party! The party started around a year ago and
>   is fairly new and I plan to keep it going. I know you will be interested
>   because reading this tells me that we share a common thing. But first
>   you need to know the address.
>
> Here are the landmarks and a guide:
>
> I'm located at a commercial area. Look for Stock Trade street and
>   expect 3 stops going there.
>
> Once you have reached the street, look for a light blue gate with a big "P"
>   on top of it. Don't get lost, a lot of parties are also held on this
>   street. Just to be sure, your name will be posted above the gate
>   unless you are not on the list.
>
> Once inside, you may ask your questions on anyone there for directions
>   because my place is big. Don't worry, a lot of people are also asking
>   and many are willing to answer.
>
> When you get to the house, my butler will give you the key to your own
>   room. That room is just made for you for being on the list. The best
>   part is, you can personalize it! Arrange it based on your personality
>   or even put a picture of yourself!
>
> During the party, you can socialize and ask other people and you may
>   gain popularity! Just make sure to have sense or else they will put
>   you down.
>
> Did you get the address? I know that after you read my invitation, you
>   will find the right party. Hope to see you here!

What's the address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every capitalized phrase is an anagram of a common Puzzling.SE tag:

- Gray Test → Strategy
- Red Lid → Riddle
- Wordy Pal → Wordplay
- Carport Gym → Cryptogram
- Swap Rods → Password
- Mr. Party Cog → Cryptogram

"Stock Trade" could be an allusion to the phrase "stock exchange", what the name for Stack Exchange is based off of; the three stops could be  the links to "All Sites", "Puzzling", and "Visit Sites" that get you from the general SE site to Puzzling.SE.

The blue gate with a big P may refer to the quote bubble logo of Puzzling (though it should be two question marks?). The name is, of course, your username, and the list is the list of registered users.

Asking for directions is asking a question, and answering is... well, answering.

Your "room" is your profile page, and the key is your password. You can personalize it by changing the text or your avatar.

"Popularity" is rep; asking good questions and responding with good answers makes you gain rep, and saying particularly nonsensical things makes other people downvote you.

So of course, the address is `puzzling.stackexchange.com`!

*(Thanks to Alconja for helping with 'Stock Trade'!)*

Comment: Beat me by 30 secs... as per my answer, I believe the "stock trade"  line is about going to www.stackexchange.com (1st stop) then to "All Sites" (2nd), then to "Puzzling" (3rd).

Comment: @Alconja: And my reputation for being slightly faster than anyone else continues! (Thanks for the help with "Stock Trade".)

Comment: That was fast haha .For "commercial area", it is the .com